# when I click twice css3 transform is not working

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I want the square rotation when I click the start button.but:

when I click once ,it is working. when I run twice ,this css3 effect is not working.

```js
$(function(){
      
 var $obj=$(".red");
 
 $("#btnStart").on("click",function(){
  $obj.removeClass("run").addClass("run");
 });
   
});
```

```css
body{padding:100px;}

.red{background:#f00;width:100px;height: 100px;}

.run{
 transform:rotate(3600deg);
 transition: transform 5s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition:transform 5s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition:transform 5s ease 0s;
 -o-transition:transform 5s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="red"></div>
 
 <br/>
 
 <button id="btnStart">
  开始旋转
 </button>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because In twice click, `$obj` has `red` class!

Comment: `$obj.removeClass("run").addClass("run");` this doesn't achieve much. It adds the class as soon as it removes it. So, before the state transition happens, it starts moving back to original state, which is what it is in currently.

Comment: very thanks for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a timeout in between removing and adding the class. Otherwise it won't recognize the change.

```js
$(function(){
  var $obj=$(".red");
  $("#btnStart").on("click",function(){
    $obj.removeClass("run");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $obj.addClass("run");
    }, 10);
  });  
});
```

```css
body{padding:100px;}

.red{background:#f00;width:100px;height: 100px;}

.run{
 transform:rotate(3600deg);
 transition: transform 5s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition:transform 5s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition:transform 5s ease 0s;
 -o-transition:transform 5s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="red"></div><br/>
    <button id="btnStart">
  开始旋转
 </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually simply reading `$obj[0].offsetHeight;` between class changes will flush the CSS and recognize the change. You don't need the `setTimeout`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ok that's nice to know. I actually didn't know that, thanks. The OP can choose to use that instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add/remove class, you can use `animate()` function of jQuery !

```js
$(function(){
      
 var $obj=$(".red");
 
 $("#btnStart").click(function(){
  $('.red').animate({  borderSpacing: -3600 }, {
                step: function(now,fx) {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
                $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
                $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
              },
              duration:'slow'
           },'linear');
 });
   
});
```

```css
body{padding:100px;}

.red{background:#f00;width:100px;height: 100px;}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="red"></div>
 
 <br/>
 
 <button id="btnStart">
  开始旋转
 </button>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately toggling requires pressing the button twice on the second go.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. I didn't see your answer !

Comment: yeah,I find it.Maybe use setTimeout is a good way.But I thank you very much.

Comment: I update my answer. Please read it again, and tell me what you think about it. I think it's better solution than add/remove class.

Comment: Performance vice I prefer css but yeah a cool answer and I'll give a +1 for you for it for taking the effort :)

Comment: thanks for you.I'm very amazed for your effort.But I need a image  'slow to fast' and change 'fast to slow' until stop.I need these animation effects.  very thx.